# How to create a NuGet Package using NuGet.Core?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I would like to create a application which makes use of the NuGet Package NuGet.Core.
It has a class called PackageBuilder that makes it possible. Is there any sample / tutorial / documentation available?

Comment: It would seem the only documentation is [one blog post](http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html). That's hardly adequate for people trying to use the library.

Comment: Polite request for documentation https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2425

Answer (score 38):

A really simple example:

1. create a folder containing the files you want in your package.
2. Write some code like this:

   ```
   ManifestMetadata metadata = new ManifestMetadata()
       {
           Authors = "mauvo",
           Version = "1.0.0.0",
           Id =  "myPackageIdentifier",
           Description = "A description",
       };

   PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
   builder.PopulateFiles("folderPath/", new[] {new ManifestFile() {Source = "**"}});
   builder.Populate(metadata);
   using(FileStream stream = File.Open(packagePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
   {
       builder.Save(stream);
   }
   ```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? The current answer seems more like a comment.

Comment: Most of that is capable with the new NuGet.Packaging Packages, as Nuget.Core isn't existing anymore.

Answer (score 8):

An improved example based on David's code. Changes:

- All files in a folder except *.nuspec are added to package.
- A row defining package file name.

  ```
  ManifestMetadata metadata = new ManifestMetadata()
  {
      Authors = "mauvo",
      Version = "1.0.0.0",
      Id =  "myPackageIdentifier",
      Description = "A description",
  };

  PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(packagePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
      .Where(f => !f.EndsWith(".nuspec"))
      .Select(f => new ManifestFile { Source = f, Target = f.Replace(path, "") })
      .ToList();
  builder.PopulateFiles("", files);
  builder.Populate(metadata);
  string packageFile = Path.Combine(packagePath, builder.GetFullName()) + ".nupkg";
  using(FileStream stream = File.Open(packageFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  {
      builder.Save(stream);
  }
  ```