# Push Nuget Package from memory

Tags: c#, nuget, roslyn

Is there a way to use Nuget.core API ( or any other ) to build and push packages from Memory ? I'm building dll using roslyn compiler and i don't have access to FileSystem so I'm not saving it to the disk, i store it as a Stream. I would like to build a package without having to save dll to filesystem and then pushing it.
I found few solutions, they seem to use "PackageBuilder" but all of them require to store files in the filesystem which is not an option in my case.
I tried to somehow modify solutions from following links, but with no luck:

[Howto create a NuGet Package using NuGet.Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808868/howto-create-a-nuget-package-using-nuget-core)

[Programatically creating a NuGet package for a local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406780/programatically-creating-a-nuget-package-for-a-local-repository)

Nuget.core documentation is quite poor and i can't find anything suitable. Did someone ever succeed with this ?

Logically thinking it seems to be doable as at the end of the day files will bo opened as Streams anyway.

Comment: Technically it should be possible indeed. The code of the PackageBuilder (https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/PackageCreation/Authoring/PackageBuilder.cs) seems to be tightly coupled to the filesystem, but you can extract the parts you need. In the end, a NuGet package is merely a zip archive with a manifest and a precise folder structure. You can definitely emulate that.